# which SD for Cohens D in psychotherapy pre-post study?

Tags: standard-deviation, pre-post-comparison, psychology, cohens-d

I'm reading a study where two groups receive two different psychotherapeutical treatments. The authors calculated Cohens D:

'In addition, we report estimates for Cohen’s d effect sizes as the adjusted mean difference of the outcome (between the groups) divided by the sample SD of the outcome at baseline.'

Why did they use the baseline SD and not the post-SD or the pooles baseline-post SD?
There were no baseline differences between the group.

Here is the link to the study: https://www.thelancet.com/journals/lanpsy/article/PIIS2215-0366(21)00158-9/fulltext

I really aprecciate any kind of help.

Comment: See, for example [this paper](https://psycnet.apa.org/doi/10.1037/1082-989X.7.1.105) and the references therein.

Comment: Greetings! It may help answerers if you provide a link to the study you refer to.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I've added the link to my question.

Answer (score 1):

This is standard practice.

You want to know the effect of treatment, scaled by it's standard deviation before you do any treatment - because that's the estimate of the treatment effect.

The treatment might have an effect on the standard deviation of the data, in which case the interpretation would be weird.

Cohen's D is just there to help with the interpretation of the size of the treatment effect.